# Knockout foreach not matching length

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, foreach

I'm having trouble displaying items from a knockout observable array.

The code below displays a length of 3 (so I know there are elements), yet the foreach does not display any rows.

```
<label data-bind="text: Data().length"></label>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">
        <tr>
            <td >woot</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result of

```
<label data-bind="text:  ko.toJSON(Data)"></label>
```

is:

```
 [ { "Description" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "fake1",
    "DeviceType" : null,
    "Policy" : null
  },
  { "Description" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "fake2",
    "DeviceType" : null,
    "Policy" : null
  },
  { "Description" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "fake3",
    "DeviceType" : null,
    "Policy" : null
  }
]
```

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: can we see your array or dataset? or how you've hooked it up on the js end? :)

Comment: I'm not a Knockout pro but here's a thought. In this line: `<label data-bind="text: Data().length">` It looks like you only get access to the array items by calling `Data()` as a function first. The array then appears to be the result of that call. But in this line: `<tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">` You are not calling the Data function. It makes me believe that this might work instead: `<tbody data-bind="foreach: Data()">` Could this be it or am I just showing my Knockout amateur status?

Comment: @ShalomAptekar added array contents to post :)

Comment: Thanks :) I was gonna take a whack at this but mg1075's answer looks pretty promising!

Comment: Can you show your ViewModel.. Are you declaring your data as a `Data = ko.observableArray()`

Comment: @rescuecreative FYI you are incorrect on your assumption, the ops bindings are correctly written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you showing *all* your javascript code in your question?
Regardless, here is a simple working example that includes a table cell for displaying the DeviceId;
hope it helps.

http://jsbin.com/UZIDira/2/edit?html,js,output

**HTML**

```
<label data-bind="text: Data().length"></label>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: DeviceId"></td>
          <td>woot</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<label data-bind="text:  ko.toJSON(Data)"></label>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myJSON = [ { "Description" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "fake1",
    "DeviceType" : null,
    "Policy" : null
  },
  { "Description" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "fake2",
    "DeviceType" : null,
    "Policy" : null
  },
  { "Description" : null,
    "DeviceId" : "fake3",
    "DeviceType" : null,
    "Policy" : null
  }
];

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Data = ko.observableArray(myJSON);  
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: You are correct, there is much, much more javascript code, your example works just fine, the problem is when I plug this into the solution as a whole it breaks down. Marked as answer as it led me towards another solution

Answer (score 2):

```
<label data-bind="text: Data().length"></label>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">
        <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: DeviceId"></td>
          <td>woot</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<label data-bind="text:  ko.toJSON(Data)"></label>  

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var JSONdata = [ { "Description" : null,
        "DeviceId" : "fake1",
        "DeviceType" : null,
        "Policy" : null
      },
      { "Description" : null,
        "DeviceId" : "fake2",
        "DeviceType" : null,
        "Policy" : null
      },
      { "Description" : null,
        "DeviceId" : "fake3",
        "DeviceType" : null,
        "Policy" : null
      }
    ];

    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Data = ko.observableArray(JSONdata);  
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

</script>
```